# macOS not-terminal: why "S-" is translated away from S-RET?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, prefix-keys

I am trying to bind `S-RET` to something, but it's getting ignored. If I do  `C-h k S-RET`, I see `RET (translated from <S-return>) runs...` - which seems to suggest that Emacs sees the `S-` in `S-RET` just fine, but then decides to drop the `S-` part for some reason. How do I find that reason and, preferably, remove it?

This is a macOS GUI build from https://emacsformacosx.com. Googling finds multiple instances of similar issue of Emacs on terminals, but in this case it is not a terminal. I have also tried looking at the translation keymap variables, I don't fully understand their contents, but at least they don't grep for anything starting with `S-R...` or `S-r...`.

Comment: Just bound what you want to `<S-return>`. See [Translation Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show us how you're attempting to bind <kbd>S-RET</kbd>, but one way is:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "S-<return>") (lambda () (interactive)
                                    (message "hello")))
```

Comment: It does work. My fault - I was debugging a certain minor mode and thought that I removed it from scenario when in fact I didn't. Thanks!